# Shopify : User maintain product at cart page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I have an doubt and explain with example.

User A, logged into the site and added the 3 ( Ball, bat and pen) products in Cart page and then logged out form the site.

Few days later, the Same User A, logged into the site using other devices or browser( Not same browser). On that case we need to display the same 3 ( Ball, bat and pen) products in Cart page.

How to implement this process to out site. please give the solution for this scenario.

Thanks,

Karthik

Comment: You have this tagged as ruby-on-rails and shopify. Which are you having trouble with in particular? Is it a Ruby on Rails app or a Shopify-hosted store? Is it a Ruby on Rails app using the Shopify API?

Comment: Why down votes? if you know the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two application for this process. please check it !

1) https://apps.shopify.com/remember-my-cart

Working process:

When a customer who may have logged in and started shopping on one device (e.g. their mobile), logs into your store on another device later (e.g. their laptop), they'll find their cart waiting for them, making it easier and more likely for them to complete their order.

2) https://apps.shopify.com/portable-cart

Working process:

Shareable Cart gives your site a “Share and Save Cart” button. When your customers press that button they’ll get a view of their shopping cart where they can share their whole cart in a single link or any products in their shopping cart on Facebook, Twitter, Pinterest, WhatsApp, Tumbler and more.

Let us know your thoughts.

Thanks,

Karthik

Answer (score 0):

When your user added items to a cart in the first instance, the contents of the cart were tied to a cookie. You know how cookies work right? So when you used a second device and logged in as that same user, you did not have that same cart cookie right? So obviously you cannot expect to have the same cart on two different devices. If you did want to support that, you would have to figure out how to persist the cart per user yourself, and ensure that any logged in users used that to sync their cart.

Comment: Thanks for the response :)

Comment: Well you could click the accept then right? I helped set you straight...